# R Extrapolate missing data by matching gps coordinates to find the missing data and then put the missing data back into the original data frame

Tags: r, missing-data

I have data frame that is missing some data in the end_station_id. It was read in properly as a csv file (3,489,749 rows) with 147,242 rows missing data as NA

I would like to fill in the missing end_station_id by finding a match using the end latitude/longitude pairs of a known end_station_id

````
```{r}
end_station_id <chr>  end_lat<dbl> end_lng <dbl>
NA                           41.92        -87.70    
NA                           41.92        -87.70
NA                           41.86        -87.63
ta52                           NA           NA
499                          41.9306      -87.7238  
255                          41.92        -87.7078
```
````

So in the above example I would like to replace the first two NAs with 255 because the gps pairs match.

I know that I have to lapply somehow but I have no clue.

The next complication comes in the form of that because the way the gps was recorded it might not be an exact match because the bicycles were put in racks and some of the bikes recorded better gps significant digits than others.

so to make the matching easier I was thinking about trying to find the mean lat/lng for each station to make the matching easier is one thought I had. So create a new DF with the unique station ids and the mean of all the gps points for each id. Then replace those mean points back into the original df so that there are only 709 station gps points.

OR

I think there are enough lat/lon points that just scanning the entire DF there should be an exact match somewhere in the data set.

So how do I do the lapply() or apply() to see if there is a match on lat/lon and then save the matching station id in the df?

It would seem I would first need a DF with no missing IDs so I can filter that to clean. Then as I find a match I cbind the fixed row to the clean DF

Sorry but I just don't have enough R training on apply( x, function) yet if that helps.

So, to finish. I have a df with missing data that could be extrapolated by comparing other columns to fill in the missing data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd worry about the accuracy of your first method. Rounding the lat/long values to two decimals wouldn't give you the matches you're looking for, as rounding the lon of station 255 to two digits would give you -87.71, which is different from the NA station lon (-87.70).

Here's an implementation of your second method, using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

# Separate data into those with and without ids
df_clean <- df %>% filter(!is.na(end_station_id))
df_na <- df %>% filter(is.na(end_station_id))

# match stations to NAs based on lat/log
df_matched <- df_na %>%
  left_join(df_clean, 
            by = c("end_lat", "end_lng"), 
            suffix = c(".na", ".clean")) %>%
  mutate(end_station_id = end_station_id.clean) %>%
  select(-end_station_id.na, -end_station_id.clean)

# Recombine data
df_cleaned <- rbind(df_clean, df_matched)
```

Maybe rounding the values before joining would give you better matching.

Another (better?/more involved) way to go about it would be to define min and max allowable values for each station, then assign the station based on being within those ranges. Or find the station that is the smallest distance away.

Comment: Thank you @Teddly. I will give this a try. I agree with you on the rounding,

Comment: My initial way was to do the min max but how to do that programmatically is beyond me in R and python.